# Select multiple options and add them to single array without using the multiple attribute

Tags: javascript

when i use this code only one item gets appended to the array and when the user select another item a new array gets created with the second selected item only how to get aroud that and append all selected items to the same array without using the multiple attribute cause its lay out isn't user friendly and i no longer have the dropdown list layout

```
<select id="drugname" name="drugname" required>
          <option value="" selected></option>
          <option value="drug1" >drug1</option>
          <option value="drug2" >drug2</option>
          <option value="drug3" >drug3</option>
        </select>

 
 function chooseOption(){
    let several= [...document.getElementById('drugname').options]
    let selected= []
    several.forEach(option => {
            if(option.selected && option.value !=''){
              selected.push(option.value)

const selectit= document.querySelector('#drugname')
```

selectit.addEventListener('change',()=>{
chooseOption()})

Comment: Simple. Declare your array *outside* your event handler.

Comment: By putting `let selected= [];` *inside* `chooseOption`, you're declaring a local that only exists during a call to `chooseOption`. To have information retained between calls, move it out of `chooseOption` so it isn't recreated every time.

Comment: Actually the function is within a class so how to make a variable global within a class ? But when i rewrite the function out of the class it worked perfect

Comment: I managed to make the variable scoop global within the class by hooking it to the constructor and defining it as any constructor property thanks very much @T.J.Crowder